# Loop only after a certain time has passed

Tags: c#

I'm pretty new to programming, I've started with C# and I'm doing a project where there is a race, basically just need to randomize the position of cars in a list, but i wanted to make it so the console updates the progress of the cars, instead of just showing initial and final position, I tried to just randomize position, show in console, clear console in a for loop with a count of 5, the problem is that it goes too fast, is there any way to make the loop only loop after a certain time to make sure it is possible to see the order of the cars change in the console?
Here's what I tried (corrida1 is a class that consists of a list of cars and the method posicaoAleatoria, which randomizes the list, corrida1.corrida is the list itself):

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                corrida1.posicaoAleatoria();
                foreach (var carro in corrida1.corrida)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("{0} conduzindo o carro número {1} de cores {2}, {3} e {4}", carro.nomePiloto, carro.numero, carro.cores, carro.marca, carro.modelo);
                }
                Console.Clear();
            }
```

Comment: welcome to SO, what you want to do is done via threading, especially with the help of the `Thread.Sleep` Method. For more information have a look in the documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.thread.sleep?view=net-6.0 .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the code as needed.
I hope I understood correctly.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            Thread.Sleep (50);
            corrida1.posicaoAleatoria();
            foreach (var carro in corrida1.corrida)
            {
                Thread.Sleep (50);
                Console.WriteLine("{0} conduzindo o carro número {1} de cores {2}, {3} e {4}", carro.nomePiloto, carro.numero, carro.cores, carro.marca, carro.modelo);
            }
            Console.Clear();
            Console.ReadKey()
        }
```

You can change the value to 50 as needed

Answer (score 2):

Use `Thread.Sleep()`. The argument for it is in milliseconds. So if you want to pause the code for say, 1 minute, it will be as follows:

`Thread.Sleep(1 * 60 * 1000);`

where 1 represents the minute, 60 the seconds in a minute and 1000 number of milliseconds in a second.

Answer (score 1):

You need [Thread.Sleep](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.thread.sleep?view=net-6.0) or [Console.Read](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.read?view=net-6.0).

Console.Read will stop the process until you enter something.